# The Limit of Nonincreasing Sets: Understanding the Author's Solution

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits, elementary-set-theory

Consider the sequence $\{C_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of nonincreasing sets. By definition $C_{k+1} \subseteq C_k$ and $\lim \limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} C_k =  \cap_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k$.

Evaluate the limit of the following definition of $C_k$

$$C_k = \Big\{x \enspace : \enspace 2 - \frac{1}{k} \enspace < \enspace x \enspace \leq \enspace 2 \enspace \Big\}$$

I can easily evaluate this limit in my mind, and it turns out that as $k$ increases without bound, the each set only has only one element in common, namely $2$. Therefore,

$$\lim \limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} C_k =  \cap_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k = \{2\}$$

However, I am attempting to understand the following solution that the author provided

*$2 \in C_k$ for every $k$, but $2 - \epsilon$ is not in every $C_k$ for each $\epsilon > 0$. This is because if $k > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, then $2-\epsilon \notin C_k$.*

which, I confess, I do not understand his reason in the second sentence.

I would appreciate if someone would provide further elucidation concerning the truth of the author's deductions.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, the existence of such $k$ follows from the fact that $\mathbb N$ is not bounded from above. Then note that $k>1/\epsilon\iff2-\epsilon<2-1/k$

Comment: @C.I.J. So the author is using the formal definition of a limit of a sequence in the solution?

Comment: The author shows that given any $\epsilon>0$ you will always find some natural $k$ such that $2-\epsilon\notin C_k$ and this clearly implies that $\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty C_k=\{2\}$